# iOS custom UIView has different layout in iphone xr and iphone 7

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout

I got auto-layout issue with custom UIView which render correctly in iphone XR
as

[image: vi]

but wrong in iphone 7s(the "Reset" button is rendered out of bound)
[image]

and setting in storyboard with just a viewcontroller(UI), and no specified UIViewController class, for simplification i just want to debug the view so i do not associate any viewcontroller class to it.

p.s Safe-area has been used

[image]

and the custom class UI(FilterView) setting:
[image]
and the custom class UI(FilterView) code:

```
override init(frame: CGRect){
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setUpView()
}
//for IB
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setUpView()
}



private func setUpView(){
    Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(Constants.NIB_FILTER_VIEW_NAME, owner: self, options: nil)
    addSubview(contentView)
    contentView.frame = self.bounds
    contentView.autoresizingMask = []
    contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true

}
```

Anyone knows what happened here?

Comment: To me it looks as though your entire FilterView is not resizing properly, not just the Reset button. It's not visible on the screenshots, but is it perhaps a fixed width view?

Comment: @SlavenkoMiljic I think you're correct too. The OP should really be using UIStackView for layout.

Comment: @SlavenkoMiljic no it is not a fixed width view

Comment: @Fogmeister i dun think using stackview solves the case

Comment: @EdisonLo UIStackView should be your default layout tool. It makes layout out view like this much easier. And it's easier to do than AutoLayout.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be creating the X button and "Sort by" label that way. What you are doing is replicating what a UINavigationController does. If you want that layout then put your view controller inside a UINavigationController and it will make it much much easier to add the X and the "Sort by" label.

Also by doing this you can add a `rightBarItem` to be your "reset" button. Again, you don't have to lay this out. UINavigationController does all that for you.

Comment: what you have suggested cannot solve the problem as the whole view is not resizing properly. In the meantime this "FilterView" is kind of modularizing as its own UI class, so changing the bar(X and Reset button) to UINavigationBar doesnt meet the idea of modularization